# Creating custom wordpress function not working

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to add a little code to an already made thumbnail plugin.

Basically i want to get the image src of an image and the just print it into the HTML, but everytime i run it, its just echoing 'Array'

This is what i have so far.

```
$testing = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post_thumbnail_id);
$html = '<a href="'.$testing.'">';
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Wordpress Documentation for [wp_get_attachment_image_src](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) the return value is:

```
An array containing:
$image[0] => url
$image[1] => width
$image[2] => height
```

Therefore, this is what you need:

```
$html = '<a href="'.$testing[0].'">';
```